# How to run docker with specific apps version?

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile, dockerpy

I'm using docker with python,when I need install some specific version of apps I docker remains me:

```
 => ERROR [3/3] RUN pip install cx-Oracle == 7.0.0 pandas == 1.1.2
```

my code in Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile, Image, Container

From python:3.7.9

ADD main.py .

Run pip install cx-Oracle == 7.0.0 pandas == 1.1.2

CMD ["python","./main.py"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with docker. `pip install` just does not like spaces between package name and version.

If you try `pip install nonexistingpackage == 1.0.0` directly in the terminal you will get the error `Invalid requirement: '=='`, before `pip` even checking if the package `nonexistingpackage` exists.

The reason is that `pip install` is using the whitespace as the delimiter between the different packages.

Remove the whitespaces:

```
RUN pip install cx-Oracle==7.0.0 pandas==1.1.2
```